# Validación de rango de fechas: que la fecha de inicio no sea mayor a la de fin

Tags: php, validación, date

Actualmente estoy trabajando un formulario de reservación de unas salas de fiesta, en la que solicito a través de un formulario la fecha de incio y la fecha en que termina el evento que se llevará acabo, actualmente tengo un problemilla, quiero validar en php que la fecha de inicio no sea mayor a la fecha final y viceversa.

El formulario llama a este archivo para realizar el insert de la reservación en la base de datos.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("funcs/conexion3.php");
include ("reservar.php");


if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];


$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')or die
("problemas al conectar");

mysql_select_db('login') or die
("problemas al conectar");

//Aqui realizo la consulta para insertar los datos en la tabla datos usarios, me traigo la variable $idUsuario del archivo perfil.php para no dejar el campo datos_usuarops.'id' vacio ya que de dejarlo vacio no inserta

//Condicional para el insert

$consulta = "SELECT id FROM solicitudes WHERE id='".$idUsuario."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$filaid = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($filaid == 0){

        $insert= mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `solicitudes`(`idminiauditorios`, `id`, `idequipos`, `nombre_sala`, `nombre_equipo`, `hora_inicio_evento`, `fecha_evento_inicio`, `fecha_evento_fin`, `hora_fin_evento`, `detalles_actividad`, `status`) VALUES ('$idmini','$idUsuario','2','$idmini','$idequipo','$hora_inicio','$fecha_reservacion','$fecha_cierre','$hora_cierre','$comentario','Informa tu pago')", $con) or die
        (mysql_error('error'));
        //$insert2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`id`, `usuario`, `password`, `nombre`, `correo`, `last_session`, `activacion`, `token`, `token_password`, `password_request`, `id_tipo`) VALUES ('','','','$nombre','','','','','','','')", $con) or die
        //(mysql_error('Error'));

                /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Buen trabajo!","Para ver el estatus de su reservación lo puede hacer a través de: Mi Perfil / Mi reservación !","success");';
                echo '}, 1000);</script>';*/

                        echo '<script>
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    swal({
                                        title: "Buen trabajo!",
                                        text: "Para ver el estatus de tú reservación lo puede hacer a través de: Mi Perfil / Mi reservación !",
                                        type: "success"
                                    }, function() {
                                        window.location = "http://extensionipcaracas.sytes.net/login/misreservaciones.php";
                                    });
                                }, 1000);
                            </script>';

        /*echo "<a href=misreservaciones.php>Solicitud exitosa, para seguir el status de su solicitud lo puede hacer a través de este enlace</a>"; Antiguo mensale de alerta*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: Publicaste mucho código, pero todo es irrelevante para tu pregunta. No estás mostrando en dónde estás obteniendo las fechas ni estás describiendo en qué formato están.

Comment: Y esta es una lectura obligatoria para lo que estás haciendo: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879).

Comment: Pasa las fechas a comparar a milisegundos y haz la comparación.

Answer (score -1):

Primero que nada empieza por arreglar tu codigo, es un completo caos sin ofender, no esta completo, no esta funcional, y es demasiado inseguro.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM solicitudes WHERE id = :idUsuario');
$stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
$stmt->execute();
$filaid = $stmt->rowCount();


if ($filaid  == 0){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO solicitudes (idminiauditorios, id, idequipos, nombre_sala, nombre_equipo, hora_inicio_evento, fecha_evento_inicio, fecha_evento_fin, hora_fin_evento, detalles_actividad, status) VALUES (:idminiauditorios, :id, :idequipos, :nombre_sala, :nombre_equipo, :hora_inicio_evento, :fecha_evento_inicio, :fecha_evento_fin, :hora_fin_evento, :detalles_actividad, :status)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':idminiauditorios', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':idequipos', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_sala', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_equipo', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hora_inicio_evento', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_evento_inicio', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_evento_fin', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hora_fin_evento', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':detalles_actividad', $);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Se ha registado la solicitud satisfactoriamente";
    }else{
        echo "No se ha registrado la solicitud";
    }
}

?>
```